# Export object, extend and re-export it in ES6

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

I want to define an object with common properties:

```
var Config = {
  a: 'fsdf',
  b: 56,
  c: 'fsfsdfsd',
  set: function set(prop, val) {
    this[prop] = val;
  }
};
```

In another file, I want to extend it with custom properties:

```
var Config = Object.assign(Config, {
  d: 34,
  e: 'qqwqw'
});
```

And then, I want to read and modify the object in other files:

```
var x = Config.d + Config.b;
Config.set('a', 'asdf');
```

At the momment I was using browserify and require and modules.export syntax. But I want to use ES6 syntax.

How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you asking how to export something using ES6 module syntax? `Object.assign` doesn't change.

Comment: The fragments I wrote are in three different files. How do you would define the export and import declarations to make this code work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exported variables are bound across modules, so you can modify imported value and it will be changed in other places

```
//config.js
const Config = {a: 'value1'};
export default Config;

//a.js
import Config from './config';
// you don't need to reassign return value, first argument will be mutated itself
Object.assign(Config, {a: 'value2'}); 

//b.js
import Config from './config';
import './a';

console.log(Config); // prints {a: 'value2'}
```

[This article](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) has more explanations about it.

Also, Rollup project homepage has a great playground to test how es6 modules works. See [this example](http://rollupjs.org/#%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22format%22%3A%22cjs%22%2C%22moduleName%22%3A%22myBundle%22%2C%22globals%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22modules%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22main.js%22%2C%22code%22%3A%22import%20Config%20from%20'.%2Fconfig'%3B%5Cnimport%20'.%2Fa'%3B%5Cn%5Cnconsole.log(Config)%3B%20%2F%2F%20prints%20%7Ba%3A%20'value2'%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22config.js%22%2C%22code%22%3A%22const%20Config%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%20'value1'%7D%3B%5Cnexport%20default%20Config%3B%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22a.js%22%2C%22code%22%3A%22import%20Config%20from%20'.%2Fconfig'%3B%5Cn%2F%2F%20you%20don't%20need%20to%20reassign%20return%20value%2C%20first%20argument%20will%20be%20mutated%20itself%5CnObject.assign(Config%2C%20%7Ba%3A%20'value2'%7D)%3B%20%22%7D%5D%7D).

Comment: In `b.js`, wouldn't be enough by importing `a.js`? Why it's also necessary to import `config.js` in `b.js` if it's already imported in `a.js`?

Comment: How do you want to get access to config.js? You can export `Config` again from `b.js`, then one import will be enough.

Comment: Ok, I understand. And there is a reason to declare Config as a constant? Why not just a variable? It seems strange modify the content of a constant.

Comment: `const` in Javascript means that you can not change the reference to object. You can't assign a new object to it, but you still can mutate that object itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a factory:

```
//config.js
export function createConfig(ext) {
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    {
      a: 'fsdf',
      b: 56,
      c: 'fsfsdfsd',
      set (prop, val) {
        this[prop] = val;
      }
    },
    ext
  );
};

//index.js
import { createConfig } from './config';

let config = createConfig({
  d: 34,
  e: 'qqwqw'
});

export config;

// x.js
import { config } from './index.js';

var x = config.d + config.b;
config.set('a', 'asdf');
```